# Django deployment - apache mod_wsgi mysql

Tags: django, apache, deployment, mod-wsgi

I have no experience setting up a web server, i need some guidance for this setup, any good articles would be appreciated.

MySQL is not mandatory. If postgres or any other django-supported DBMS is easier to setup or more efficient, that would do as well.

Comment: what kind of server? Windows, Linux, which flavour of Linux? You should probably ask this question better on serverfault.com.

Comment: Have you tried following the documentation? What is not working for you?

Comment: @marue Linux, some flavor of ubuntu perhaps.

@DanielRoseman i have read django documentation about mod_wsgi but with so many technologies going around i thought it would be wise to ask people with prior django deployment experience.

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't mention if you were deploying to linux or windows, I'm going to assume linux for my answer.

Jacob Kaplan Moss did a workshop last year at pycon, and the video is available here:

http://ontwik.com/python/django-deployment-workshop-by-jacob-kaplan-moss/

It is a pretty long video (3hrs) but it covers a lot of topics and is a good way to learn a lot in a short amount of time. The code that he used during the workshop is available on github:

https://github.com/jacobian/django-deployment-workshop

If you prefer to read instead of watch, here is a good article from the caktus group, describing how they deploy using virtualenv, fabric, pip, and rsync.

http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2010/04/22/basic-django-deployment-with-virtualenv-fabric-pip-and-rsync/

And last but not least here is a link on django deployments with mod_wsgi from the offical django documentation.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/

I hope this gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: just went to his talk on the same subject at this year's pycon. It is very easy to follow. Download the code on his github, go to notes/pycon2011/script.txt and start to follow along.

Comment: Also perhaps watch my talk around common things that can go wrong when setting up mod_wsgi. See http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6#Conference_Presentations

Comment: @Aaron I imagine Kaplan Moss workshop being excellent for developers with prior knowledge on server deployment, but all these technologies are so vast for my little configuration. :)

Comment: @tsiokos You're probably right about the whole stack and load balancing and all. However, you should really try it. It shows you how to install the basic things you need (apache2, mod_wsgi, postgres database) in a way that is more straightforward than any other doc I've seen. I'd also recommend checking out @Graham Dumpleton's suggestion... he's the man who wrote mod_wsgi and his documentation is pretty great.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Excellent presentation, something to get me started, thank you. I have one question though, how bad is the performance impact on script preloading issues, the problem is solved after the first request?

Comment: Delays on first request due to lazy loading of application depends on the framework/application. Flask overhead is minimal, Django a bit more and something like TurboGears quite significant because of potential number of package dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: if you are not interested in a [RTFM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) approach: please stop reading.

For the web server it is actually very easy to have an Apache instance installed on your [Linux/Unix](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/install.html) or [Windows](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html). Installation on [other platforms](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/) is also treated.

Apache default configuration is OK in the most of (development) cases, so to configure Apache to work with Django is just a matter of reading the awesome [official mod_wsgi documentation](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/), in particular [installation instructions](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationInstructions) first and [Integration with Django](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango) then.

About the database it's also very easy. I'm adopting sqlite for development (efficient, no installation and no configuration). For production I'd probably use sqlite again or Postgres for "high traffic" sites.

Happy reading!